# flowdocument pagination - forcing elements to appear on a new page

Tags: wpf, pagination, flowdocument

when i print a flow document, I want certain elements - paragraphs, tables - probably marked with some attached property  to:

- be transferred to a new page if they do not fit entirely on the previous one
  or
- always appear on a new page.

Has anybody done it already or has an idea how to do it?

Cheers

Comment: I guess it's <Block BreakPageBefore="true">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are on the right track for the permanent page break.

The 'Paragraph' object has a property called 'KeepTogether' which would achieve your first bullet point.  If the blocks within the 'Paragraph' do not all fit on one page, all of the blocks will be moved to the next page.  There is also the similar property 'KeepWithNext' which allows provides the same behavior, but groups 'Paragaph' siblings together.